# View mobile screen on PC using adapter

Tags: android, adapter, hdmi

I need to view the live screen of my Android mobile on a Windows PC. My Android phone has a mini-HDMI output. **Is there any adapter/software that helps me to achieve this?** The applications that I found after searching needs the device to be rooted to control it. I don't want to remotely control the device. I just need to get the live feed from the mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the HDMI port, you'd need something that can accept HDMI input.

Very few computers can do so (except possibly some smart-tv type boxes).

However, there's a good chance that the monitor connected to your computer can.  It might even have a spare input.

In other words, displaying your phone's output "in a window" on your monitor is extremely difficult.  But by pushing a button or swapping a cable, you may well be able to display your phone's output on the entire monitor, in place of the computer's.

Practically speaking, if you need it in a window, or the device doesn't have HDMI out, the most common solution seems to be a high-end webcam in a fixture to aim it at the device.  I saw a presentation that was delivered this way, displaying on very large flatscreen TVs, and didn't even realize that the slides were coming from an Android tablet as seen by an overhead camera until the presenter picked up the tablet and slid a phone into it's place.

Comment: I am not sure if he means he wants a live video on his computer or on a monitor/tv. If it's a monitor, then it's easier, but with a computer it'd require a lot of expensive hardware, not to mention the huge performance loss it would cause to the device.

Comment: Oh, I expect on the computer itself is what is wanted, I'm proposing the monitor or the webcam as more practical.

Comment: plenty of video input devices available for PC. They cost a few dollars, but hardly expensive (compared to a good tablet/smartphone/pc) or rare. I'm sure you could shoehorn an HDMI signal into one of them...

Comment: @JulianHigginson - I did look in response to your mention, and it looks like there might be some boards with digital in, though nowhere near the low prices of analog or digital-TV-receiver solutions.  Do you have evidence that one of these boards could do the job?  If so, that would be a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are [some relatively affordable HDMI-DVI adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002HZWEIC) on the market. Couple them with [a mini-HDMI to full HDMI cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ES5ZR8) and you've got yourself a decent hardware setup.

Some notes:

- HDMI carries audio and video, while DVI carries only video. However, [the two have no difference in video quality](http://www.ecoustics.com/electronics/products/articles/122868.html), and they use the same encoding.
- as Mgamerz said, support for the HDMI outputs on Android phones has been, thus far, dismal. Your phone might have the port, but your ROM might not support it. Furthermore, some apps won't even acknowledge the existence of the HDMI, again, because so few phones have them.

From a hardware and an encoding point of view, this is COMPLETELY possible, but from a software point of view, it is likely IMPOSSIBLE. If you figure out how to do what you're trying, definitely tell as many people as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need HDMI mirroring, which means you'll need a high end device (most likely dual cores), and support for it is going to have to be built into the rom. I own an atrix, and developers have slaved for months to get HDMI mirroring on it, but only some progress has been made.
Otherwise, unless your device supports it, you won't be able to do it. It's dependent on hardware too.

Edit: There might be some apps to do it but I doubt they will achieve what you seek. HDMI mirroring typically doesn't go past 20fps either (on a dual core 1Ghz).

Answer (score 0):

http://mymobiler.com/?cat=3

Try this app from mymobiler. it works on motorola atrx 2 with android 2.3.6 rooted. 
The site lists only a few supported models but it seems working on other models too.

You can get the full access to the mobile screen in your windows application windows. 
It can also capture screenshots and take video of the actions on the screen.